# Reponse.Write output in another aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, response.write

I have below page_load method on  one aspx page. Now, I want to get string xmlData in another aspx page in string variable. is there a way that i can get  the value of xmlData variable on another page?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlData = "text for this example"
            Response.Write(xmlData);
        }
```

Comment: Use session object

Comment: Those pages are in different project but in one solution. is there not any way that I pass the the path of that page and get the value from reponse.write on page?

Comment: there are tons of examples here, just search a little bit

Comment: If there are multiple project in your application then you can use `Application` Object to store value.

Comment: User controls are the mechanism for sharing rendered content, and they can be loaded/rendered programmatically

Comment: You can try `Server.Transfer` check the example [here](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/avi_sanjay/Server.Transfer.htm06172006162238PM/Server.Transfer.htm.aspx)

Comment: See, I have this aspx page (lets say page1) but there is no option on frontend so i can load the page1 and get the value in session or whatever and use it on page2. the situation is I have page2 which I have option to load from frontend. Now, I need to hit the page1 from page2 to get the value of string variable. I hope this clears the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked for me with below code -

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
Server.Execute("/page1.aspx", writer);
```

Now, writer has value which was written in xmlData variable in page1.aspx.

Thank you guys for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string xmlData = "text for this example";
        Session["xmlData"] = xmlData;
    }

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        string xmlData = "text for this example";
        ViewState["xmlData"] = xmlData;
    }
```

you can use session or ViewState to store the string data in another page.

session remain till the entire session page, need to be destroyed.
just like Session["xmlData"]="".

ViewState variable automatic destroy in next page.

Comment: See, I have this aspx page (lets say page1) but there is no option on frontend so i can load the page1 and get the value in session or whatever and use it on page2. the situation is I have page2 which I have option to load from frontend. Now, I need to hit the page1 from page2 to get the value of string variable. I hope this clears the requirement.

 public partial class page1

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a complete solution for posting a xml http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10430/Post-XML-Data-to-an-ASP-NET-Page-using-C:
To send xml:

```
 WebRequest req = null;
 WebResponse rsp = null;
 try
 {
  string fileName = "C:\test.xml";
  string uri = "http://localhost/PostXml/Default.aspx";
  req = WebRequest.Create(uri);
  //req.Proxy = WebProxy.GetDefaultProxy(); // Enable if using proxy
  req.Method = "POST";        // Post method
  req.ContentType = "text/xml";     // content type
  // Wrap the request stream with a text-based writer
  StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
  // Write the XML text into the stream
  writer.WriteLine(this.GetTextFromXMLFile(fileName));
  writer.Close();
  // Send the data to the webserver
  rsp = req.GetResponse();

 }
 catch(WebException webEx)
 {

 }
 catch(Exception ex)
 {

 }
 finally
 {
  if(req != null) req.GetRequestStream().Close();
  if(rsp != null) rsp.GetResponseStream().Close();
 }

private string GetTextFromXMLFile(string file)
{
 StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(file);
 string ret = reader.ReadToEnd();
 reader.Close();
 return ret;
}
```

To read xml:

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
     page.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
    // Read XML posted via HTTP
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(page.Request.InputStream);
    String xmlData = reader.ReadToEnd(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the structure basically.

//You cant load this page from front end

```
public partial class page1
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlData = "text for this example"
            Response.Write(xmlData);
        }
}
```

//Second Page - This page can be load from frontend on button click

```
public partial class page2
{

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            string xmlData = //code here to get string from page1
        }
}
```